# Simplest way to upload my code?

Tags: c++, boost

I have been working on my projects using Boost library. And need to upload the source code to my school homepage. The grader needs to grade my code compiling it.

The problem is

1. What if the grader does not have Boost library?
2. What would be the simplest way for me to upload my work on the school page?

Boost libraries total are like 300MB.

Do I really need to import every single hpp header file onto one folder
and zip it to upload?

One thing I can think of.

I copy all the boost header files into my project folder so that I do not have to include the files from the original boost library folder.

It's gonna be pretty messy because I would have to revise every boost library header files to indicate the separately copied files.

Any good idea??

Comment: It is "Code", not "Codes". :)

Comment: Just tell them to download Boost at http://www.boost.org/users/download/

Comment: Just ask your supervisor if he has boost installed..

Comment: @stefan it's not always a good idea, as installed boost version may be unexpected.

Comment: Have you considered asking your teacher or supervisor what to do? They probably know better than random strangers on the web.

Comment: @molbdnilo But looking for solutions before asking brings him into the situation to be able to make proposals for a solution, when he is asking.

Comment: I would say that it's a fairly essential part of the assignment to know whether you're allowed to use boost or not, given that the grader has to be able to build it (rather than just look at the source).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably use only a small fraction of boost, so you can separate parts of Boost you are using via [boost bcp](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/tools/bcp/doc/html/index.html) and upload only that ones.

But boost is often used library, there is a big chance, your teacher uses it, so ask him. He will most likely provide you a solution even if he doesn't use boost.